# Public attribute appears as undefined when dynamically assigning click event to element in Angular

Tags: angular, canvas

I have a problem adding events inside a canvas. I have a canvas with several images and I have the ID of all of them in my "diagram" variable. I would like to click on the element, I look for the ID in the diagram array, and display this description. In the code below my diagram appears as undefined and I don't understand why. Thank you very much in advance

```
export class EngineComponent implements OnInit {

  public diagram = [
    {itemName: 'st', itemType: 'start', description: 'Beginning of the manufacturing process'},
    {
      itemName: 'op2',
      itemType: 'operation',
      description: 'Production process of the items'
    },
    {
      itemName: 'op3',
      itemType: 'operation',
      description: 'Error in the product packaging process'
    }
  ]

  click(item: any) {
    const itemName = item.target.parentElement.id;

    item = this.diagram.find(p => p.itemName === itemName);

    if (item) {
      this.showDescription = item.description;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.diagram.forEach(item => {
      document.getElementById(item.itemName)
        .addEventListener('click', this.click.bind(this.diagram));
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its
>   `this` keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of
>   arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

So replacing your `click()` function with following should work as expected

```
public click(event: any) {
  const itemName = event.currentTarget.id;

  Object.keys(this).some((key) =>  {
    if (this[key].itemName === itemName) {
      this.showDescription = this[key].description; 
    }
  });
}
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-udgyfv)